# Testing a Web application with an emulator

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, jquery-mobile, symbian

i am currently a mobile web application with jquery mobile. Is there a way of testing the application with an emulator that works for ipad, ios, blackberry, android, symbian and other major os on my local machine without connecting to the internet or using a real phone or hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To avoid connecting to the internet: run your server on localhost
2. To avoid using actual hardware, use the emulators that come with the SDKs for the platforms you're interested in. But at first, just use the computer browser; I'd recommend Safari, as it is based on WebKit, like iOS and Android use.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the ripple project. Currently its a chrome extension for emulating different devices. Sure it has shortcomings but it can be very useful for certain situations.

http://ripple.incubator.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

One thing I tend to do is use FireFox with [user agent switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) plugin. This allows you to configure a series of user-agent identifiers in your browser to 'fool' your jQuery mobile website into thinking it's dealing with particular devices.

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is to load a mobile url and see how it looks on different phones you could try this site

http://www.synthphone.com/